# Append meta tag to head

Tags: jquery, dom, append, meta-tags

Please help me. I am trying to append some meta tags to head.There was no error in page.But it is appending correctly.what may be the problem.Please help me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('head').append('<meta property="og:title" content="Example Title" />');
    $('head').append('<meta property="og:description" content="Example Title Description" />');
});
```

Comment: Looks and works fine for me

Comment: perhaps, you may be missing to load jquery

Comment: A problem could be that the opengraph crawler which scans your site does not execute the javascript and does not see the meta tags appended. The tags should be inserted into the html on the server side. (Assuming that is what you want)

Comment: Are you looking into the source code or into the dom tree of the page?

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/guCX9/

Comment: Yes I'm looking the source code.

Comment: Running any javascript does not change the source code but only the live dom tree (eg accessible via developer tools/inspect element). The source code is what comes from the server. The DOM tree is what the browser generates from the source code and what javascript can operate on. The og-crawler (eg facebook) only sees the source code. But javascript can only operate on the DOM. If you look in the DOM you will see that the code you posted works fine. But nevertheless it will probably not achieve what you want. You need to modify the source code, not the dom. This can only be done on the server

Comment: Yes.It's working..but i don't know what is missing

Comment: Thankyou Laszlo and sorry for my big mistake.